# Change Install Location of Node RPM using bb/Speculate

Tags: node.js, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am new to building my own RPMS. I am using Speculate to generate a .tar and .spec file then building the RPM. When I generate the .spec file I am unable to select the install location? In the  Speculate JSON I can do post actions cp etc, but cannot choose install location or pre options ?

I am trying to do something like this with speculate

```sh
    %install
    mkdir -p %{buildroot}/opt/%{name}
    cp -r ./ %{buildroot}/opt/%{name}
```

Current Spec JSON

to perform any actions after installing your package (such as moving files on the target server) you can specify these inline using the `post` property:

```
{
  "spec": {
    "post": [
      "mv /usr/lib/my-cool-api/rc.local /etc/rc.local"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this possible to do in JSON with Speculate ?  - Docs: https://github.com/bbc/speculate
Thanks for your time!